# How can I have the same model several time in a Laravel relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an app where the users can have trainings attached to them with a little description.
So, they can have a training in High School and the description they attach is "Rockford High School". However, I want them to be able to put several times the same type, so they could have 3 High School, or University, etc.

However, when I try to attach two times the same model with the same id, one gets overwritten. I thought that using an intermediate model would solve the issue, but it didn't.

Here are my migrations and any relevant code.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Training extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name_french', 'name_english'];

    public function candidates() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Candidate')->using('App\CandidateTraining')->withPivot('description');
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\SanitizeIds;
use App\Salary;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Candidate extends Model
{

    use SanitizeIds;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'address',
        'field_of_work',
        'formations',
        'work_experiences',
        'interests'
    ];

    public function trainings() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Training')->using('App\CandidateTraining')->withPivot('description');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class CandidateTraining extends Pivot
{
    //
}
```

```
Schema::create('trainings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name_french');
    $table->string('name_english');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('candidate_training', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('candidate_id');
    $table->string('training_id');
    $table->string('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('candidates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('phone_number');
    $table->string('address');
    $table->string('field_of_work')->default('{}');
    $table->string('formations')->default('{}');
    $table->string('work_experiences')->default('{}');
    $table->string('interests')->default('{}');
    $table->string('cv')->default('');
    $table->string('video_cv')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I don't get how I could make this work and I haven't found any answer during my research. I also want the user to be able to edit them eventually, so delete one model with x id without deleting all the others with the same id but different description.

Comment: We need to see the code code where you attach the trainings? this is doable :)

Answer (score 0):

Call me an idiot but am thinking something like this would make sense for your situation:

```
Schema::create('trainings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name_french');
    $table->string('name_english'); 
    // You should checkout 'spatie/laravel-translatable' package, that 
    // way you can use one column for 'name' and then translate it in realtime
    // depending on your application locale.
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('candidate_practice', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->string('candidate_id');
   $table->string('training_id');
   $table->timestamps(); // Probably not needed
});

Schema::create('practices', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->foreignId('candidate_id')
         ->constrained()
         ->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->string('description');
   $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('candidates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('phone_number');
    $table->string('address');
    $table->string('field_of_work')->default('{}');
    $table->string('formations')->default('{}');
    $table->string('work_experiences')->default('{}');
    $table->string('interests')->default('{}');
    $table->string('cv')->default('');
    $table->string('video_cv')->default('');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now you can create multiple practices related to a user by a `one-to-many` relationship which is a lot easier to edit individually or delete without stepping on other resources and then relate practices to training.

With this, creating a `CandidatePractice.php` pivot class is no longer necessary.